# How to post a job on Monster.com from .net MVC application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am developing a solution for posting a job offer directly from our mvc .net application. Referring the link - http://doc.monster.com/real-time-posting  but no luck and it doesn't have proper steps.

I have created XML but not able to proceed further. Can you please guide me on this?

```
string strBuilder = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><SOAP-ENV:Header><mh:MonsterHeader xmlns:mh='http://schemas.monster.com/MonsterHeader'>            <mh:MessageData>              <mh:MessageId>Company Jobs created on 09/08/2011 02:41:44 PM</mh:MessageId>              <mh:Timestamp>2011-09-08T14:41:44Z</mh:Timestamp>            </mh:MessageData>          </mh:MonsterHeader>          <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/04/secext'>            <wsse:UsernameToken>              <wsse:Username>xrtpjobsx01</wsse:Username>              <wsse:Password>rtp987654</wsse:Password>            </wsse:UsernameToken>          </wsse:Security>        </SOAP-ENV:Header>        <SOAP-ENV:Body>  ";
        // started job section
        strBuilder= strBuilder+"<Job jobRefCode='myownjobreferencecode' jobAction='addOrUpdate' inventoryType='transactional' jobComplete='true' xmlns='http://schemas.monster.com/Monster' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:schemaLocation='http://schemas.monster.com/Monster          http://schemas.monster.com/Current/xsd/Monster.xsd'>  ";

        // recruiter information
        strBuilder = strBuilder + "<RecruiterReference><UserName>xrtpjobsx01</UserName></RecruiterReference>";

        // job information
        strBuilder = strBuilder + "<JobInformation><JobTitle>Product developement manager </JobTitle><JobLevel monsterId='12'/>";

        // job type, status and salary
        strBuilder = strBuilder + "<JobType monsterId='1'/><JobStatus monsterId='4'/><Salary><Currency monsterId='1'/><SalaryMin>100000.00</SalaryMin><SalaryMax>150000.00</SalaryMax><CompensationType monsterId='1'/></Salary>";

        // contact information
        strBuilder = strBuilder + "<Contact hideAll='false' hideAddress='true' hideStreetAddress='true' hideCity='true' hideState='true' hidePostalCode='true' hideCountry='true' hideContactInfoField='false' hideCompanyName='false' hideEmailAddress='true' hideFax='true' hideName='false' hidePhone='true'><Name>John</Name>";
        strBuilder = strBuilder + "<CompanyName>John's Company</CompanyName><Address><StreetAddress>1 John Street</StreetAddress><StreetAddress2>PO Box 1</StreetAddress2><City>Johnstown</City><State>PA</State><CountryCode>US</CountryCode><PostalCode>15955</PostalCode></Address><Phones><Phone phoneType='work'>999-999-9999</Phone></Phones><E-mail>john@johnscompany.com</E-mail></Contact><PhysicalAddress><StreetAddress>5 Clock Tower</StreetAddress><StreetAddress2>Suite 500</StreetAddress2><City>Maynard</City><State>MA</State><CountryCode>US</CountryCode><PostalCode>01754</PostalCode></PhysicalAddress>";

        // apply online
        // strBuilder = strBuilder + "<DisableApplyOnline>false</DisableApplyOnline><HideCompanyInfo>false</HideCompanyInfo>";

        // job body
        strBuilder = strBuilder + "<JobBody>Job body for a product development manager</JobBody><AdditionalSearchKeywords>additional search keyword</AdditionalSearchKeywords><EducationLevel monsterId='1'/>";

        // apply with monster
        /* strBuilder = strBuilder + "<ApplyWithMonster><DeliveryMethod  monsterId='2'/><DeliveryFormat  monsterId='2'/><EmailAddress>recruiter@testers.com</EmailAddress>";
        strBuilder = strBuilder + "<VendorText>job vendor text</VendorText><PostURL>http://www.testdomain.com/awm/apply</PostURL><ApiKey>EAAQ3sampleMNfAK9q4</ApiKey></ApplyWithMonster>";*/
        strBuilder = strBuilder + "</JobInformation>";

        // job posting
        strBuilder = strBuilder + "<JobPostings><JobPosting desiredDuration='60' bold='true'><InventoryPreference><Autorefresh desired='true'><Frequency>7</Frequency></Autorefresh><CareerAdNetwork desired='true'><Duration>14</Duration></CareerAdNetwork></InventoryPreference>";
        strBuilder = strBuilder + "<Location><City>Boston</City><State>MA</State><CountryCode>US</CountryCode><PostalCode>02125</PostalCode></Location><JobCategory monsterId='47'/><JobOccupations><JobOccupation monsterId='11909'/></JobOccupations><BoardName monsterId='1'/><DisplayTemplate monsterId='1'/><Industries><Industry><IndustryName monsterId='1'/></Industry></Industries>";

        // video
        // strBuilder = strBuilder + "<Video monsterId='123' refCode='video_A'></Video>";

        strBuilder = strBuilder + "</JobPosting>            </JobPostings>          </Job>        </SOAP-ENV:Body>      </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
        string uri = "https://gateway.monster.com:8443/bgwBroker";
        //HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        var req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        //req.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy(); // Enable if using proxy
        req.Method = "POST";        // Post method
        req.ContentType = "text/xml";     // content type
        // Wrap the request stream with a text-based writer
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
        // Write the XML text into the stream
        writer.WriteLine(strBuilder);
        writer.Close();
        // Send the data to the webserver

        var rsp = req.GetResponse();  
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream());
        string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
        Response.Write(result);
```

Comment: Please add the code you have so far.

Comment: And the error you get.

Comment: Error is - JobBoard ID [1] is not valid for company [34889333]. Apply online URL was not supplied. It was defaulted. ­

Comment: The link you provided states "Clients may choose to post to the following boards based on their available purchased inventory, as well as clients' desired distribution and targeting."
Is it maybe something to do with your account permissions or having insufficient credits to post on the main board (ID[1])?

Comment: Building XML via string concatenation is insane. Create an object model and serialize it.